# Create function from code

Tags: .net, vb.net, refactoring

I have been asked to edit the following code...

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If DateTime.Now.Hour >= 6 And DateTime.Now.Hour < 12 Then
        Message.Text = "Good Morning."
    End If

    If DateTime.Now.Hour >= 12 And DateTime.Now.Hour <= 17 Then
        Message.Text = "Good Afternoon."
    End If

    If DateTime.Now.Hour > 17 Or DateTime.Now.Hour < 6 Then
        Message.Text = "Good Evening"
    End If
End Sub
```

and change it into a function. The original code basically displays one of the messages on a webpage when opened depending what time of day it is. I was looking for some help on how or what I need to change to turn it into a function.

I have edited the code below, but only slightly so anything that looks completely wrong will be because I have only edited a small part of it so the ByVal in the function I have to not tried to implement into the function as I am a bit stuck.

```
Private Function Greetings(goodMorning as string, goodAfternoon as String, goodEvening as String) as String

    Dim outPut As String

    If DateTime.Now.Hour >= 6 And DateTime.Now.Hour < 12 Then
            Message.Text = "Good Morning."
    ElseIf
        DateTime.Now.Hour >= 12 And DateTime.Now.Hour <= 17 Then
        Message.Text = "Good Afternoon."
    ElseIf
        DateTime.Now.Hour >= 12 And DateTime.Now.Hour <= 17 Then
        Message.Text = "Good Afternoon."

    Return outPut
End Function
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What is this function supposed to do?  Have you given it any thought or effort before asking us to do it for you?  Happy to help, not happy to do your work for you.

Comment: Apologies for not explaining in more detail. I am trying just to get the code to show on a webpage the correct output when a i open the page. So far i have tried this...

Comment: The ultimate point of a function is to return something.  What is your function supposed to return?  That's a pretty good place to start.

Comment: I'm sorry your question isn't sufficiently clear. What would you even be using the session variable for? Your attempt doesn't even use the variables you are passing into the function.

Comment: this is my first attempt at a function as i have only just started learning VBS, i will edit my question so i can hopefully explain better.

Comment: Reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/sect4ck6.aspx) would probably be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a pointer rather than the full answer because that won't help you in the long run.

Ideally your page load needs to look like this

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Message.Text = GetGreeting(DateTime.Now.Hour)

End Sub
```

Now you need to create a Function that matches the argument you need to pass in - in this case the Hour as an integer and it needs to return a String of the greeting.

Comment: Thank you matt for your help, i will give it a go and see what i can do but how you explained helped